# Visual Studio Sql Server project cannot compile (dacpac generation ) with External source of type 6

Tags: visual-studio, azure-synapse

I am trying to do a Sql Project in visual studio (out of a Azure Sql Pool formerly SQL Datawarehouse ) . However I am getting an issue while the engine is parsing my external datasource with managed identity. The external data source code is the following :

```
SQL
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [data_toto_dfs_core_windows_net] WITH (LOCATION = N'abfss://data@toto.dfs.core.windows.net')
```

And the error code is the following :

> Error     An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements
> of type
> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlExternalDataSource:
> Unsupported external data source type '6'.

Any idea how to deal with it ?

Regards

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a database scoped credential which helps to access the external data source.

Make sure your external data source have permission to Managed Identity for accessing the data.

Please go through this document [Database-scoped credential with Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-storage-files-storage-access-control?tabs=managed-identity#database-scoped-credential) for more information.